# Use independent resource for each thread in QtConcurrent::mapped

Tags: c++, qt

I am processing a bunch of heavy data(1000 or more of them) by QtConcurrent::mapped

```
 auto result = QtConcurrent::mapped(image_id, std::bind<std::pair<QString, QImage>>(&mainWindow::process_image_impl, this, ph::_1));
```

instead of

```
void process_image_impl(int image_id)
{
  //.......lots of codes

  {
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    morphology.close(image, image); //I don't want to lock this operation
  }

  //lots of codes
}
```

I would like to do something like

```
void process_image_impl(int image_id)
{
  //.......lots of codes


    morphology[thread_id].close(image, image); //I don't want to lock this operation


  //lots of codes
}
```

in the function process_image_impl, I call a class called “morphology”, I don’t want to 
lock the class “morphology” when I process the image, but if I don’t lock it I may 
cause undefined behavior.Instead of locking the process, I would like to put the 
class “morphology” in a container and call each of the “morphology” according to 
the thread in the QThreadPool, is this possible?Or do you have other suggestions?Thanks

Comment: I think you need to look into thread local storage, but Qt doesn't have a cross platform implementation of it, so you'll need to use the one[s] native to your platform[s].

Answer (score 0):

multithreading is one of the possible solutions depending on how many times your "morphology" class will be called and what operating system you'll be using to run your code and what processor you'll be using and so on. all the above will affect the performance of your code at run time which depends on what you exatly expect. in case you want to take the multithreading approach all you need to do is create a pointer to your "morphology" class and another one to a "QThread" then move it to the thread using "moveToThread(&thread)". for example check this link: [how one should actually and rightfully implement multithreading in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html)

also mutithreading is one way if you want your program to be responsive and not locked up in processing

Answer (score 0):

### If morphology needs to be accessed only within a thread

```
QThreadStorage<Morphology> morphology;

void process_image_impl(int image_id) {
  //lots of codes
  if (!morphology.hasLocalData()) morphology.setLocalData(Morphology());
  morphology.localData().close(image, image);
  //lots of codes
}
```

### If morphology needs to be accessed outside of a thread also

```
template <class T>
class ThreadSafeStack: private QStack<T*> {
  QMutex mutex;
public:
  T* pop() {
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    return !isEmpty() ? QStack::pop() : new T;
  }

  void push(T* &t) {
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    QStack::push(t);
  }
};

ThreadSafeStack<Morphology> stack;

void process_image_impl(int image_id) {
  //lots of codes
  Morphology *morphology = stack.pop();
  morphology->close(image, image);
  stack.push(morphology);
  //lots of codes
}
```